# How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), PARTITION by another column in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of player performance:

```
CREATE TABLE TopTen (
  id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  home INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `datetime`DATETIME NOT NULL,
  player VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  resource INT NOT NULL
);
```

What query will return the rows for each distinct `home` holding its maximum value of `datetime`? In other words, how can I filter by the maximum `datetime` (grouped by `home`) and still include other non-grouped, non-aggregate columns (such as `player`) in the result?

For this sample data:

```
INSERT INTO TopTen
  (id, home, `datetime`, player, resource)
VALUES
  (1, 10, '04/03/2009', 'john', 399),
  (2, 11, '04/03/2009', 'juliet', 244),
  (5, 12, '04/03/2009', 'borat', 555),
  (3, 10, '03/03/2009', 'john', 300),
  (4, 11, '03/03/2009', 'juliet', 200),
  (6, 12, '03/03/2009', 'borat', 500),
  (7, 13, '24/12/2008', 'borat', 600),
  (8, 13, '01/01/2009', 'borat', 700)
;
```

the result should be:

| id | home | datetime | player | resource |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 04/03/2009 | john | 399 |
| 2 | 11 | 04/03/2009 | juliet | 244 |
| 5 | 12 | 04/03/2009 | borat | 555 |
| 8 | 13 | 01/01/2009 | borat | 700 |

I tried a subquery getting the maximum `datetime` for each `home`:

```
-- 1 ..by the MySQL manual: 

SELECT DISTINCT
  home,
  id,
  datetime AS dt,
  player,
  resource
FROM TopTen t1
WHERE `datetime` = (SELECT
  MAX(t2.datetime)
FROM TopTen t2
GROUP BY home)
GROUP BY `datetime`
ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
```

The result-set has 130 rows although database holds 187, indicating the result includes some duplicates of `home`.

Then I tried joining to a subquery that gets the maximum `datetime` for each row `id`:

```
-- 2 ..join

SELECT
  s1.id,
  s1.home,
  s1.datetime,
  s1.player,
  s1.resource
FROM TopTen s1
JOIN (SELECT
  id,
  MAX(`datetime`) AS dt
FROM TopTen
GROUP BY id) AS s2
  ON s1.id = s2.id
ORDER BY `datetime`
```

Nope. Gives all the records.

I tried various exotic queries, each with various results, but nothing that got me any closer to solving this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column for each distinct value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-for-each-distinct-value-of)

Comment: Duplicate of (slightly newer) question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql

Answer (score 1105, accepted):

You are so close!  All you need to do is select BOTH the home and its max date time, then join back to the `topten` table on BOTH fields:

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM topten tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM topten
    GROUP BY home) groupedtt 
ON tt.home = groupedtt.home 
AND tt.datetime = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

Comment: Test it for distinct, if two equal max datetime be in the same home (with different players)

Comment: I think the classic way to do this is with a natural join:

"SELECT tt.* FROM topten tt NATURAL JOIN
  (
  SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS datetime FROM topten GROUP BY home
  ) mostrecent;"

Same query exactly, but arguably more readable

Comment: If it is a very large table it would take ages if there is no index on home.

Comment: How would this query look in SQLite?

Comment: I'm confused where the table tt comes from?

Comment: why not `SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime,player,resource
    FROM topten
    GROUP BY home`,am I miss something?

Comment: what about if there are two rows which have same 'home' and 'datetime' field values?

Comment: Can somebody tell please why not `select * from topten GROUP BY home ORDER BY datetime DESC` ?

Comment: @Young the problem with your query is that it may return `id`, `player` and `resource` of non-max row for a given home i.e. for home = 10 you may get :
`3  | 10  | 04/03/2009 | john   | 300`  
In other words it doesn't guarantees that all column of a row in resultset  will belong to max(datetime) for given home.

Comment: @me1111 problem with your query is that it may/may not return row ith max(datetime) for a given home. Reason being GROUP BY will fetch any random row for each home and ORDER BY will just sort the overall all result as produced by GROUP BY

Comment: @Parker Using a `NATURAL JOIN` like that may work for this (simple) case, but is not generally reliable, as it won't always eliminate all the rows it should for more complicated tables. For production views, it is safer to explicitly specify the join-condition.

Comment: @KemalDuran so-called 'window functions' are probably the best way to handle this situation in modern databases (if it's possible that two or more rows may have identical values in both the "home" and "datetime" fields). AFAIK MySQL lacks these but others such as Postgres now have them.

Comment: Many people have pointed out issues offering no counter example that shows a better solution...just makes the reader hesitant on implementing the answer.

Comment: Regarding @KemalDuran 's comment above , if there are two rows with the same home and datetime fields, what you need to do is take Michael La Voie 's solution and add `MAX(id) AS MaxID` to the inner `SELECT` statement and then go and add another line `AND tt.id = groupedtt.MaxID` at the end.

Comment: @cardamom, why should that pick only the distinct values ?

Comment: @sactiw, I could not understand what you said as a reply to Young's comment. Let me quote from your comment :'the problem with your query is that it may return id, player and resource of non-max row for a given home'- why should that happen as `GROUP BY` is applied and `MAX(datetime)` is picked up ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed his query would return "Maximum of Certain Column per Group" but what we really need here is "The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column". For further details refer examples under: [mysql queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/examples.html)

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed it took me a short while to remember what I was doing when I used this solution and wrote that comment. @KemalDuran asked _what about if there are two rows which have same 'home' and 'datetime' field values?_  My comment above adds a 3rd grouping to fix that problem, around the `id` field which is **definitely** a unique one unlike say datetime or player. @MichaelLaVoie 's solution has 2 groupings and some of us needed this solution for situations where that was not enough.

Comment: Will not work if there are two duplicates for max values

Comment: How do I do this in EF Core?

Answer (score 151):

The fastest `MySQL` solution, without inner queries and without `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT m.*                    -- get the row that contains the max value
FROM topten m                 -- "m" from "max"
    LEFT JOIN topten b        -- "b" from "bigger"
        ON m.home = b.home    -- match "max" row with "bigger" row by `home`
        AND m.datetime < b.datetime           -- want "bigger" than "max"
WHERE b.datetime IS NULL      -- keep only if there is no bigger than max
```

**Explanation**:

Join the table with itself using the `home` column. The use of `LEFT JOIN` ensures all the rows from table `m` appear in the result set. Those that don't have a match in table `b` will have `NULL`s for the columns of `b`.

The other condition on the `JOIN` asks to match only the rows from `b` that have bigger value on the `datetime` column than the row from `m`.

Using the data posted in the question, the `LEFT JOIN` will produce this pairs:

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|              the row from `m`            |    the matching row from `b`   |
|------------------------------------------|--------------------------------|
| id  home  datetime     player   resource | id    home   datetime      ... |
|----|-----|------------|--------|---------|------|------|------------|-----|
| 1  | 10  | 04/03/2009 | john   | 399     | NULL | NULL | NULL       | ... | *
| 2  | 11  | 04/03/2009 | juliet | 244     | NULL | NULL | NULL       | ... | *
| 5  | 12  | 04/03/2009 | borat  | 555     | NULL | NULL | NULL       | ... | *
| 3  | 10  | 03/03/2009 | john   | 300     | 1    | 10   | 04/03/2009 | ... |
| 4  | 11  | 03/03/2009 | juliet | 200     | 2    | 11   | 04/03/2009 | ... |
| 6  | 12  | 03/03/2009 | borat  | 500     | 5    | 12   | 04/03/2009 | ... |
| 7  | 13  | 24/12/2008 | borat  | 600     | 8    | 13   | 01/01/2009 | ... |
| 8  | 13  | 01/01/2009 | borat  | 700     | NULL | NULL | NULL       | ... | *
+------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Finally, the `WHERE` clause keeps only the pairs that have `NULL`s in the columns of `b` (they are marked with `*` in the table above); this means, due to the second condition from the `JOIN` clause, the row selected from `m` has the biggest value in column `datetime`.

Read the [SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) book for other SQL tips.

Comment: With `SQLite`, the first one is much much slower than La Voie's version when there is no index on the matched column (i.e. "home"). (Tested with 24k rows resulting in 13k rows)

Comment: This is the best answer, if you show the execution plan you will see one step less with this query

Comment: what will happen if 2 rows have the same `home` and `datetime` and the `datetime` is the maximum for that particular `home` ?

Comment: Both rows appears in the result set. This answer is a proof of concept. In your real code you probably have another criterion to select only one of them in this situation (maybe the first one or the last one or you use another column to decide). Just add this criterion as a new condition in the `ON` clause. F.e. `... ON ... AND m.id < b.id` to keep the most recent entry (the one with the greatest `id`) when two rows have the same values in `home` and `datetime` columns and it is the maximum `datetime`.

Comment: What indexes would best optimize for a query like this?

Comment: @AjaxLeung an index on the columns `home` and `datetime`. As a general rule, an index helps if it contains the columns used in the `ON`, `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clauses. However, it depends on how the columns are used. An index is useless if the column is used in an expression. Put [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) in front of the query to [find out what indexes are used (and how)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html).

Comment: Beware of self-joins. They are unsuitable if the groups are large, because for each group, they combine each row in that group with each other row in that group. This is quadratic in the group size. A group of 1000 rows will explode to a million. This (possibly absurd) set of rows is _only filtered out at the end_, after it has already been worked on. This is easily observed against two large data sets of the same total size, one with many results (small groups), the other with few results (large groups). The query with larger groups will be far, far slower, despite returning fewer rows.

Answer (score 81):

Here goes **T-SQL** version:

```
-- Test data
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (id INT, home INT, date DATETIME, 
  player VARCHAR(20), resource INT)
INSERT INTO @TestTable
SELECT 1, 10, '2009-03-04', 'john', 399 UNION
SELECT 2, 11, '2009-03-04', 'juliet', 244 UNION
SELECT 5, 12, '2009-03-04', 'borat', 555 UNION
SELECT 3, 10, '2009-03-03', 'john', 300 UNION
SELECT 4, 11, '2009-03-03', 'juliet', 200 UNION
SELECT 6, 12, '2009-03-03', 'borat', 500 UNION
SELECT 7, 13, '2008-12-24', 'borat', 600 UNION
SELECT 8, 13, '2009-01-01', 'borat', 700

-- Answer
SELECT id, home, date, player, resource 
FROM (SELECT id, home, date, player, resource, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY home ORDER BY date DESC) N
    FROM @TestTable
)M WHERE N = 1

-- and if you really want only home with max date
SELECT T.id, T.home, T.date, T.player, T.resource 
    FROM @TestTable T
INNER JOIN 
(   SELECT TI.id, TI.home, TI.date, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TI.home ORDER BY TI.date) N
    FROM @TestTable TI
    WHERE TI.date IN (SELECT MAX(TM.date) FROM @TestTable TM)
)TJ ON TJ.N = 1 AND T.id = TJ.id
```

**EDIT**
Unfortunately, there are no RANK() OVER function in MySQL.
But it can be emulated, see [Emulating Analytic (AKA Ranking) Functions with MySQL](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/03/29/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html?page=3).
So this is **MySQL** version:

```
SELECT id, home, date, player, resource 
FROM TestTable AS t1 
WHERE 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM TestTable AS t2 
            WHERE t2.home = t1.home AND t2.date > t1.date
    ) = 0
```

Comment: @MaxGontar, your mysql solution rocks, thx. what if in your @_TestTable you remove row#1>: SELECT 1, 10, '2009-03-04', 'john', 399 , this is, what if you have a single row for a given home value? thx.

Comment: BUG: Replace "RANK()" with "ROW_NUMBER()".  If you have a tie (caused by a duplicate date value) you will have two records with "1" for N.

Answer (score 30):

This will work even if you have two or more rows for each `home` with equal `DATETIME`'s:

```
SELECT id, home, datetime, player, resource
FROM   (
       SELECT (
              SELECT  id
              FROM    topten ti
              WHERE   ti.home = t1.home
              ORDER BY
                      ti.datetime DESC
              LIMIT 1
              ) lid
       FROM   (
              SELECT  DISTINCT home
              FROM    topten
              ) t1
       ) ro, topten t2
WHERE  t2.id = ro.lid
```

Comment: added lid field in table, No Good

Comment: This one didn't execute on PHPMyAdmin. Page refreshes but there's no result nor error..?

Comment: `WHERE   ti.home = t1.home` - can you explain the syntax ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: what exactly is that you don't understand here? It's a correlated query, and the expression you mention is a correlation condition.

Comment: @Quassnoi, The `select` query that has the  line `WHERE ti.home = t1.home`  does not need the `FROM` clause that defines `t1`. So how is it used ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html

Answer (score 21):

I think this will give you the desired result:

```
SELECT   home, MAX(datetime)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY home
```

**BUT** if you need other columns as well, just make a join with the original table (check `Michael La Voie` answer)

Best regards.

Comment: He needs other columns also.

Comment: id, home, datetime, player, resource

Answer (score 16):

Since people seem to keep running into this thread (comment date ranges from 1.5 year) isn't this much simpler:

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM topten ORDER BY datetime DESC) tmp GROUP BY home`

No aggregation functions needed...

Cheers.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

Error Message: Column 'x' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: This definitely won't work in SQL Server or Oracle, though it looks like it might work in MySQL.

Comment: This is really beautiful! How does this work? By using DESC and the default group return column? So if I changed it to datetime ASC, it would return the earliest row for each home?

Comment: This straight-up doesn't work if you have nonaggregated columns (in MySQL).

Answer (score 11):

You can also try this one and for large tables query performance will be better. It works when there no more than two records for each home and their dates are different.  Better general MySQL query is one from Michael La Voie above.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.home, t1.date, t1.player, t1.resource
FROM   t_scores_1 t1 
INNER JOIN t_scores_1 t2
   ON t1.home = t2.home
WHERE t1.date > t2.date
```

Or in case of Postgres or those dbs that provide analytic functions try

```
SELECT t.* FROM 
(SELECT t1.id, t1.home, t1.date, t1.player, t1.resource
  , row_number() over (partition by t1.home order by t1.date desc) rw
 FROM   topten t1 
 INNER JOIN topten t2
   ON t1.home = t2.home
 WHERE t1.date > t2.date 
) t
WHERE t.rw = 1
```

Comment: Is this answer correct? I tried to use it, but it seams not to select the record with newest date for 'home', but only removes record with oldest date. Here's an example: [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ab25/1/0)

Comment: @kidOfDeath - Updated my reply with context and Postgres query

Comment: With `SQLite`, the first one is much much slower than La Voie's version when there is no index on the matched column (i.e. "home").

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT  tt.*
FROM    TestTable tt 
INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT  coord, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime 
        FROM    rapsa 
        GROUP BY
                krd 
        ) groupedtt
ON      tt.coord = groupedtt.coord
        AND tt.datetime = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

Answer (score 8):

This works on Oracle:

```
with table_max as(
  select id
       , home
       , datetime
       , player
       , resource
       , max(home) over (partition by home) maxhome
    from table  
)
select id
     , home
     , datetime
     , player
     , resource
  from table_max
 where home = maxhome
```

Comment: how does this pick the max datetime? he asked to group by home, and select max datetime. I dont see how this does that.

Answer (score 8):

Try this for SQL Server:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT home, MAX(year) AS year FROM Table1 GROUP BY home
)
SELECT * FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN cte ON a.home = cte.home AND a.year = cte.year
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is MySQL version which prints only one entry where there are duplicates MAX(datetime) in a group.

You could test here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a4ae/1

### Sample Data

```
mysql> SELECT * from topten;
+------+------+---------------------+--------+----------+
| id   | home | datetime            | player | resource |
+------+------+---------------------+--------+----------+
|    1 |   10 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | john   |      399 |
|    2 |   11 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | juliet |      244 |
|    3 |   10 | 2009-03-03 00:00:00 | john   |      300 |
|    4 |   11 | 2009-03-03 00:00:00 | juliet |      200 |
|    5 |   12 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | borat  |      555 |
|    6 |   12 | 2009-03-03 00:00:00 | borat  |      500 |
|    7 |   13 | 2008-12-24 00:00:00 | borat  |      600 |
|    8 |   13 | 2009-01-01 00:00:00 | borat  |      700 |
|    9 |   10 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | borat  |      700 |
|   10 |   11 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | borat  |      700 |
|   12 |   12 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | borat  |      700 |
+------+------+---------------------+--------+----------+
```

### MySQL Version with User variable

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ord.*,
        IF (@prev_home = ord.home, 0, 1) AS is_first_appear,
        @prev_home := ord.home
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.id, t1.home, t1.player, t1.resource
        FROM topten t1
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS mx_dt
            FROM topten
            GROUP BY home
          ) x ON t1.home = x.home AND t1.datetime = x.mx_dt
        ORDER BY home
    ) ord, (SELECT @prev_home := 0, @seq := 0) init
) y
WHERE is_first_appear = 1;
+------+------+--------+----------+-----------------+------------------------+
| id   | home | player | resource | is_first_appear | @prev_home := ord.home |
+------+------+--------+----------+-----------------+------------------------+
|    9 |   10 | borat  |      700 |               1 |                     10 |
|   10 |   11 | borat  |      700 |               1 |                     11 |
|   12 |   12 | borat  |      700 |               1 |                     12 |
|    8 |   13 | borat  |      700 |               1 |                     13 |
+------+------+--------+----------+-----------------+------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Accepted Answers' outout

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM topten tt
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM topten
    GROUP BY home
) groupedtt ON tt.home = groupedtt.home AND tt.datetime = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
+------+------+---------------------+--------+----------+
| id   | home | datetime            | player | resource |
+------+------+---------------------+--------+----------+
|    1 |   10 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | john   |      399 |
|    2 |   11 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | juliet |      244 |
|    5 |   12 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | borat  |      555 |
|    8 |   13 | 2009-01-01 00:00:00 | borat  |      700 |
|    9 |   10 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | borat  |      700 |
|   10 |   11 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | borat  |      700 |
|   12 |   12 | 2009-04-03 00:00:00 | borat  |      700 |
+------+------+---------------------+--------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Altho I love this answer, as this is helping me so much, I have to point to one major flaw, that it dependat on used mysql system. Basically, this solution relies on ORDER BY clause in subselect. This MIGHT, or MIGHT NOT work in various mysql environment. I haven't tried it on pure MySQL, but for sure this doesn't work RELIABLY on MariaDB 10.1, as explained here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372511/mysql-order-by-inside-subquery

but the very same code does work ok on Percona Server. To be precise, you MIGHT, or MIGHT NOT get the same results, depending on amount of t1 columns.

Comment: The example for this statement is, that on MariaDB 10.1 it worked, when I used 5 columns from t1 table. As soon as I added sixth column, obviously messing with the "natural" data sort in original table, it stopped working. The reason is, the data in subselect became un-ordered and thus I had "is_first_appear=1" condition met several times. The very same code, with same data, worked on Percona ok.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 FROM table1 WHERE c3 = (select max(c3) from table)

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE c3 = (select max(c3) from table1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to gt the most recent row per group using a sub query which basically calculates a rank for each row per group and then filter out your most recent rows as with rank = 1

```
select a.*
from topten a
where (
  select count(*)
  from topten b
  where a.home = b.home
  and a.`datetime` < b.`datetime`
) +1 = 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37a0d/16)

Here is the [visual demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37a0d/17) for rank no for each row for better understanding

> By reading some comments **what about if there are two rows which have same 'home' and 'datetime' field values?**

Above query will fail and will return more than 1 rows for above situation. To cover up this situation there will be a need of another criteria/parameter/column to decide which row should be taken which falls in above situation. By viewing sample data set i assume there is a primary key column `id` which should be set to auto increment. So we can use this column to pick the most recent row by tweaking same query with the help of `CASE` statement like

```
select a.*
from topten a
where (
  select count(*)
  from topten b
  where a.home = b.home
  and  case 
       when a.`datetime` = b.`datetime`
       then a.id < b.id
       else a.`datetime` < b.`datetime`
       end
) + 1 = 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2f025/2)

Above query will pick the row with highest id among the same `datetime` values

[visual demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2f025/3) for rank no for each row

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL 8.0 this can be achieved efficiently by using `row_number()` window function with common table expression.

(Here `row_number()` basically generating unique sequence for each row for every player starting with 1 in descending order of resource. So, for every player row with sequence number 1 will be with highest resource value. Now all we need to do is selecting row with sequence number 1 for each player. It can be done by writing an outer query around this query. But we used common table expression instead since it's more readable.)

Schema:

```
 create  TABLE TestTable(id INT, home INT, date DATETIME, 
   player VARCHAR(20), resource INT);
 INSERT INTO TestTable
 SELECT 1, 10, '2009-03-04', 'john', 399 UNION
 SELECT 2, 11, '2009-03-04', 'juliet', 244 UNION
 SELECT 5, 12, '2009-03-04', 'borat', 555 UNION
 SELECT 3, 10, '2009-03-03', 'john', 300 UNION
 SELECT 4, 11, '2009-03-03', 'juliet', 200 UNION
 SELECT 6, 12, '2009-03-03', 'borat', 500 UNION
 SELECT 7, 13, '2008-12-24', 'borat', 600 UNION
 SELECT 8, 13, '2009-01-01', 'borat', 700
```

Query:

```
 with cte as 
 (
     select id, home, date , player, resource, 
     Row_Number()Over(Partition by home order by date desc) rownumber from TestTable
 )
 select id, home, date , player, resource from cte where rownumber=1
```

Output:

| id | home | date | player | resource |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2009-03-04 00:00:00 | john | 399 |
| 2 | 11 | 2009-03-04 00:00:00 | juliet | 244 |
| 5 | 12 | 2009-03-04 00:00:00 | borat | 555 |
| 8 | 13 | 2009-01-01 00:00:00 | borat | 700 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50d491089baa4d84093e0c70ce9f867f)*

Answer (score 4):

This works in SQLServer, and is the only solution I've seen that doesn't require subqueries or CTEs - I think this is the most elegant way to solve this kind of problem.

```
  SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
    FROM TopTen
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY home
                                ORDER BY [datetime] DESC)
```

In the `ORDER BY` clause, it uses a window function to generate & sort by a `ROW_NUMBER` - assigning a `1` value to the highest `[datetime]` for each `[home]`.

`SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES` will then select one record with the lowest `ROW_NUMBER` **(which will be 1)**, as well as all records with a tying `ROW_NUMBER` **(also 1)**

As a consequence, you retrieve all data for each of the 1st ranked records - that is, all data for records with the highest `[datetime]` value with their given `[home]` value.

Comment: This answer got me where I needed to go with Firebird3.  (I didn't need/use the `WITH TIES` keywords.)

Answer (score 3):

Why not using:
SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime,player,resource FROM topten GROUP BY home
Did I miss something?

Comment: That would only be valid with MySQL, and only versions before 5.7 (?) or after 5.7 with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled, since it is SELECTing columns that have not been aggregated/GROUPed (player, resource) which means MySQL will provide randomly chosen values for those two result fields. It would not be a problem for the player column since that correlates to the home column, but the resource column would not correlate with the home or datetime column and you could not guarantee which resource value you'd receive.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, BUT w.r.t the asked question this query won't return the `expected` output in MySQL version 5.6 and `before` and I highly doubt it to behave otherwise in MySQL version 5.7 and `after`.

Comment: @simpleuser, ` It would not be a problem for the player column since that correlates to the home column` - can you explain more ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed as I look at it again, that statement is incorrect. I had thought each player always had the same home value, but I see now that they do not, so the same random select issue will occur for that column as well

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select * from mytable a join
(select home, max(datetime) datetime
from mytable
group by home) b
 on a.home = b.home and a.datetime = b.datetime
```

Regards
K

Comment: Test it for distinct, if two equal max datetime be in the same home (with different players)

Comment: the alias for `max(datetime) ` is `datetime`. Won't it make any problem ?

Comment: How is the highest `datetime` selected ?

Answer (score 2):

@Michae The accepted answer will working fine in most of the cases but it fail for one for as below.

In case if there were 2 rows having HomeID and Datetime same the query will return both rows, not distinct HomeID as required, for that add Distinct in query as below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tt.home  , tt.MaxDateTime
FROM topten tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM topten
    GROUP BY home) groupedtt 
ON tt.home = groupedtt.home 
AND tt.datetime = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

Comment: result shows - "#1054 - Unknown column 'tt.MaxDateTime' in 'field list'"

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed do you have MaxDatetime filed i.e any column name like that..?

Comment: No, the table in OP does not have any such column.

Comment: the error also saying the same please..what exactly you wanna do ? can u send the table structure and your query.

Answer (score 1):

this is the query you need:

```
 SELECT b.id, a.home,b.[datetime],b.player,a.resource FROM
 (SELECT home,MAX(resource) AS resource FROM tbl_1 GROUP BY home) AS a

 LEFT JOIN

 (SELECT id,home,[datetime],player,resource FROM tbl_1) AS b
 ON  a.resource = b.resource WHERE a.home =b.home;
```

Comment: can you explain your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope below query will give the desired output:

```sql
Select id, home,datetime,player,resource, row_number() over (Partition by home ORDER by datetime desc) as rownum from tablename where rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

*(NOTE: The answer of Michael is perfect for a situation where the target column `datetime` cannot have duplicate values for each distinct `home`.)*

If your table has **duplicate rows for `home`x`datetime` and you need to only select one row for each distinct `home` column**, here is my solution to it:

Your table needs one unique column (like `id`). If it doesn't, create a view and add a random column to it.

Use this query to select a single row for each unique `home` value. Selects the lowest `id` in case of duplicate `datetime`.

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM topten tt
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT min(id) as min_id, home from topten tt2
    INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT home, MAX(datetime) AS MaxDateTime
        FROM topten
        GROUP BY home) groupedtt2
    ON tt2.home = groupedtt2.home
    ) as groupedtt
ON tt.id = groupedtt.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer doesn't work for me if there are 2 records with same date and home. It will return 2 records after join. While I need to select any (random) of them. This query is used as joined subquery so just limit 1 is not possible there.
Here is how I reached desired result. Don't know about performance however.

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id order by datetime desc separator ','),',',1) as id, home, MAX(datetime) as 'datetime'
 from topten
 group by (home)
```